# Proper usage of aws create-data-set [aws cli]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I have setup a data-source with the following:

```sh
aws quicksight create-data-source --cli-input-json file://connection.json
```

cat connection.json:

```
{
    "AwsAccountId": "44455...",
    "DataSourceId": "abcdefg13asdafsad",
    "Name": "randomname",
    "Type": "S3",
    "DataSourceParameters": {
        "S3Parameters": {
            "ManifestFileLocation": {
                "Bucket": "cmunetcoms20",
                "Key": "asn-manifest.json"
            }
          }
        }
}
```

asn-manifest.json contains (and is placed in the appropriate bucket):

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "https://cmunetcoms20.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ASN_Scores.csv"
            ]
        },
        {
            "URIPrefixes": [
                "prefix1",
                "prefix2",
                "prefix3"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "textqualifier": "'",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```

This successfully creates a data-source and then when I go to create a data-set I use

```sh
aws quicksight create-data-set --cli-input-json file://skeleton
```

skeleton contains:

```
{
    "AwsAccountId": "44455...",
    "DataSetId": "generatedDataSetName",
    "Name": "test-asn-demo",
    "PhysicalTableMap": {
        "ASNs": {
            "S3Source": {
                "DataSourceArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-2:444558491062:datasource/cmunetcoms20162031",
                "InputColumns": [
                {
                "Name": "ASN",
                "Type": "INTEGER"
                },
                {
                "Name": "Score",
                "Type": "DECIMAL"
                },
                {
                "Name": "Total_IPs",
                "Type": "INTEGER"
                },
                {
                "Name": "Badness",
                "Type": "DECIMAL"
                }
                ]
            }
      }
    },
    "ImportMode": "SPICE"
}
```

Throws the following error:

> "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the
>   CreateDataSet operation: Input column ASN in physical table ASNs has
>   invalid type. Allowed types for S3 physical table are [String]"

If I change each Type to "String", it throws the following error:

> An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the
>   CreateDataSet operation: Insufficient SPICE capacity

There is plenty of SPICE on the account, something like 51 GB, and almost 0 utilization. Additionally, I ran the numbers and the total amount of Spice that I think should be used for this data set is approximately 0 GB. (size 71k rows, 4 columns, each column as a string to pad my calculation).

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question mentions ' create-data-set ' but in the code you run 'create-data-source'

Answer (score 2):

Got it fam. The solution for me was a regional configuration problem. My s3 bucket was in us-east-2 and my quicksight was in us-east-1. Trying to create a data set in a region that is not ur primary account (even though you have enterprise), causes a spice error since alternate regions are not given any spice balance to start out.